# Symlink and folder permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, symlink

Say I want to create a symlink for a folder `/media/drive/here` (owned by a group) to a folder `/home/pepe/private/here`
Do all the intermediate folders need to have the x bit on?

What does the computer do when from `/media/drive` I execute cd here?  Does it internally just `cd /home/pepe/private/here`? (I had to set the x bit in this situation to every intermediate folder, so that other users could access just my private folder here, but still not sure if this is correct, I thought only permissions on `/home/pepe/private/here` matters, not their parents folders)

Comment: basicly yes, you'll have to chmod +x all the hirrarcy to allow OTHERS to access the folder. Another why around this is to use `bind` mount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement @Rabin's comment, you can confirm this by `stat`'ing `root` path:

```
# stat /
  File: '/'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fe01h/65025d    Inode: 2           Links: 23
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-01-03 11:51:24.202486304 +0000
Modify: 2016-06-20 16:31:24.210935643 +0100
Change: 2016-06-20 16:31:24.210935643 +0100
 Birth: -
```

If `root` didn't have `o+x` bit set, you would not be able to access your home directory as a regular user.

Symbolic links are basically used to keep things simple. For instance in most systems `/lib` and `/lib64` point to exact same location, otherwise those would be copies of the same directory.

Also note the excerpt from `man chmod`:

> chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.

Hence you cannot change the privileges of the `symlinks` and your user must be privileged to access all the resources which `symilinks` are traversing.

Comment: But then, what is the purpose of a symbolic link? Just to be able to type less to use a directory? I thought it could also be used to give access to a dirextory that otherwise wouldn't be accesible by certains users..

Comment: @dami: you can use `mount --bind src dest` instead. This will do what you want.